# Calling module , 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have module with name Ioanv1:

```
...
person1={"temp_lags": [-21.96,-21.82,-21.89,-21.99]}
...
def ....
```

Now I want to replace person1 with new data in another script:

```
import json
import Ioanv1

person1={"temp_lags": [-21,-21,-21,-21]}
jsonToPython = Ioanv1(person1)
print(jsonToPython)
```

I get TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Error message is simple and clear.

Ioanv1 is module

You are using `Ioanv1(person1)` which you can not.
You probably want something like: `Ioanv1.person1`

Comment: how can I fix it? Now I want to replace person1

Comment: `loanv.person1 = person1`? You want to replace person1 from loanv (so `loanv.person1=`) with local person1.

Comment: Thank you. the error is gone but new data has not replaces!

Comment: import json import Ioanv1

person1={"temp_lags": [-21,-21,-21,-21]}   Ioanv1.person1 = person1